# Using old RAID configured disk after new disk has been used in the controller

Tags: raid

I have Dell Poweredge T100 server with Dell SAS 6 and two hard disk on RAID 1.

Last week the server died including one RAID 1 hard disk. We sent the server for repair and the problem with PSU was fixed. But the repair guys also checked the RAID controller by configuring new RAID with their test hard disk.

Now if I install one working RAID 1 disk and one new disk, will the RAID controller let me continue my old RAID 1 and resync the new disk and continue?

What I fear is the RAID controller will want the test hard from repair guys. Thus I have to re configure RAID 1 forcing me to wipe the working disc. If so, I've to backup the working disc, reconfigure RAID 1 and reinstall? Or is there better way?

Note: I'm using DELL SAS confiugratio utility to manage RAID. (Press CTRL+C after BIOS)

Answer (score 0):

If the Dell RAID controller doesn't see your degraded RAID 1 array when you reinsert the good disk, you can just [import it from the RAID BIOS](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/storage/RAID/PERC5/en/UG/HTML/chapterh.htm#wp1069383).